# Only some Font Awesome glyphs display in WPF

Tags: wpf, font-awesome

I am attempting to use Font Awesome in a WPF app.  It half works. That is, some glyphs are picked up and show, others show a rectangle.

I'm following guides correctly, I think, but something is going wrong!

Here's a code snippet

```
<Window.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular</FontFamily>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Text="&#xf15c;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Red" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="100"/>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Text="&#xf15a;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Red" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The fonts are installed in a Fonts directory

[image: Font Directory]

And Marked as Resource

[image]

And this is what it shows on the screen

[image]

You can see that the first icon xf15c; displays as expected but the second one xf15a; does not.  Generally, most do not display.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the .otf file, you can see the name of the font. This is what you need to use to the FontFamily resource, without the file extension.
Try the following code:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="Icons">pack://application:,,,/{YOUR PROJECT NAME};component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</FontFamily>
```